# How To Remove Dashboard Menu Items for Multisite Users?

Tags: multisite, user-roles, dashboard

I'm trying to remove some menu items in the Dashboard of Multisite users. For example my domain name is xyz.com, his site will be xyz.com/user.

When he logs in to WP Dashboard under xyz.com/user/wp-admin, how can I (the admin of xyz.com) remove some options from xyz.com/user (left sidebar) menu?

For example, I would like to remove user's ability to Add New Users?

Any response will be appreciated. Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1) Install & network activate [User Role Editor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/) plugin from http://example.com/wp-admin/network/plugins.php

2) Then go to **Settings > User Role Editor** menu on network and make sure you have the settings as shown in following screenshot.

[image]

3) Go to "User Role Editor" settings page on your main site http://example.com/wp-admin/users.php?page=users-user-role-editor.php and select the "Administrator" role. Then remove the capabilities which you want to remove. For example, in below screenshot you can see that all User related capabilities have been removed. Do note that I have checked "Apply to All Sites" so that it applies to all the sites on the network.

[image]

4) Now check backend of any of your subsite and you will notice that "Users" menu is no more there. Similarly you can hide other menu pages as intended. Let me know how it goes :-)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed information! Exactly what I needed :)